# Why division is always ZERO?

Tags: c#

```
int value = 10 * (50 / 100);
```

The expected answer is 5, but it is always zero. Could anyone please give me detail explanation why it is?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Because you are using `int`: `50/100=0`

Comment: 5 is also an int? Am I wrong?

Comment: (50 / 100) is evaluated first, and the result of an integer division discards the fraction part.

Comment: `decimal value = 10m * (50m / 100m)`

Comment: `5` is an int, but the result of `50/100` isn't `5`, it's `0.5`. Which is not an int. So instead you get 0, since 100 fits exactly 0 times into 50.

Comment: @Nyerguds Understood. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Because the result of `50/100` is 0 .

`50/100` is equals to `int(50/100)` which returns `0`.

Also, if you want to return `5`, use this:

```
int value = (int)(10 * (50 / 100.0));
```

The result of `(50/100.0)` is `0.5`.

Comment: Make sense.....

Answer (score 2):

Because you're doing an integer division: `(50 / 100)` gives `0`

Try this:

```
int value = (int)(10 * (50 / 100.0));
```

Or reverse the multiply/division

```
int value = (10 * 50) / 100;
```

So it's getting multiplied before the divide

Comment: Make sense.....

Answer (score 1):

You make operation on int values.
`50/100` in `int` is `0`.