# Math.Round for a decimal number

Tags: c#, math, rounding

**Code:**

```
double PagesCount = 9 / 6 ;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(PagesCount, 0));
```

I'm trying to round the answer to 9/6(1,5) to 2 but this code snippet always results in 1.
How can I avoid that?

Comment: Your variable `PagesCount` is already equal to 1, because result of expression `9 / 6` is 1 (integer division in C# also returns integer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why division is always ZERO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278585/why-division-is-always-zero)

Comment: duplicate: [Why does integer division in C# return an integer and not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851273/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`9 / 6` is an [integer division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-) which returns an integer, which is then cast to a double in your code.

To get double division behavior, try

```
double PagesCount = 9d / 6 ;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(PagesCount, 0));
```

(BTW I'm picky but [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netcore-3.1) in the .net world refers base 10 numbers, unlike the base 2 numbers in your code)

Comment: thank you! will it approved later. So would you recommend to just use a decimal?

Comment: It really depends on the case, `decimal` computations are slower but more precise. You'd  use them for financial calculations for instance (hence the m suffix for money).

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Round` is not the problem here.

`9.0 / 6.0 ==> 1.5` but `9 / 6 ==> 1` because in the second case an integer division is performed.

In the mixed cases `9.0 / 6` and `9 / 6.0`, the `int` is converted to `double` and a `double` division is performed. If the numbers are given as `int` variables, this means that is enough to convert one of them to `double`:

```
(double)i / j ==> 1.5
```

---

Note that the integer division is complemented by the modulo operator `%` which yields the remainder of this division:

```
9 / 6 ==> 1
9 % 6 ==> 3
```

because `6 * 1 + 3 ==> 9`